# FFMpeg hello world failed

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm new to the ffmpeg development.

I've got my ffmpeg via ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/download.html using

```
   `git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg`
```

My OS is Win7. I'm using Cygwin to help me work under a Unix-like environment.

I'm using tutorial code from http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.html. My current code is Tutorial01.

So I've got my gcc, ffmpeg and code together. Working directory is /ffmpegDemo,

code: /ffmpegDemo/tutorial01.c

ffmpeg: /ffmpegDemo/ffmpeg

And I use command `gcc-I ffmpeg -o t01 tutorial01.c` to compile my code.
(cygwin doesn't support "copy", here're just some major message:)

> libavutil/avconfig.h: No such file or directory
>
> ...
>
> error: 'CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO' undeclared
>
> ...

and others are just warnings.

Indeed, there's no avconfig.h under ffmpeg/libavutil. I've looked for 'CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO', here's this reference: [http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/avcodec_8h.html](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/%7Eismail/ffmpeg-docs/avcodec_8h.html) says that 'CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO' is defined in libavcodec/avcodec.h. I've checked avcodec.h and didn't find any.

I was very confused about this error and confused about all the "configure" and "make" things that I saw while searching for answer. Am I doing it wrong? Did I miss some steps? Hope that I could find an answer here.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install the libraries? You seem to have just cloned the source & are trying to build the tutorials w/o actually building & installing the library from the source

Comment: no I didn't install the libraries. I don't have much exp using opensource libs. I know there's something wrong, but I don't know how and why building and installing libs. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Oh ... in that case you need to build the libraries using configure & make. You can refer to `README` & `INSTALL` documents for the instructions. Or as @ncite has suggested you can pick up win32 built library. I would suggest you give building the source a try... that is why we have opensource libraries so that we can modify & build on our own ^^

Comment: Thanks very much. I would like to configure & make to build the source too. I guess it would help me get a better understanding. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to compile it with the the command provided by tutorial?

```
gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lavutil -lm
```

There are lots of API changes in FFMpeg and the tutorial hasn't been updated for a while. But I believe at least tutorial01 should work.

Comment: thanks for answering. just tried but thousands of errors pop out. I've already move the code to /ffmpegDemo/ffmpeg to fit the command's requirement. the most confusing thing is that why libavutil/avconfig.h, which is included in the other ffmpeg header files, doesn't exist and the field that should be in the header doesn't exist either.

Comment: ooo, one more thing, as  another.anon.coward stated, have you compiled the ffmpeg source code before using it? If you don't want the compile/make issues, you can just try with an Win32 build, like this one: http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/builds/

Comment: thanks the help of both of you. Seems I did it wrong in the first place. I thought using the source code would be enough, but I should have them built into libs and my codes linked to the libs to work finally. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, you are correct. You need to compile your library first. Maybe you already figure it out by now, but for your case you can check: http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#Compilation-under-Cygwin

Comment: working on it. thanks again for your patient and detailed answer.